# Delphi - IDE plugin/extension to copy/move components and related events code between units

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is there any extension which allows me to copy or move components between units/forms, including all the code assigned to their events? For example... a `TButton` with some code in its `OnClick` event, it should copy both the component and the code in the event.

edit: fixed "its"/"it's", incorrectly modified by mod who edited my question text.

Comment: Not that I know of, but it would be very convenient! That's one thing I never knew I missed. :)

Comment: I move components very often between forms as I redesign UI for applications, it's a big pain when I have to manually move all the related code for the events.

Comment: You could try to make an IDE wizard. If you manage to get the IOTASourceEditor interface for the current form or data module, you can try to find all methods assigned to events of the selected components. You can override the cut, copy and paste actions, but I would rather create a separate functionality for this, because you may not always want the code to be copied too. As far as I can tell by looking at the OTA interfaces you will need to do some parsing yourself.

Comment: @ David maybe trivial but very time consuming, imagine f.e moving various menus/submenus, panels with various checkboxes, buttons etc, it's an arduous time-consuming process going through copying every code in every single event and re-assigning/pasting it on the destination form.

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Copying is not how to develop software. You need to re-use rather than copy.

Comment: Moving between forms while re-designing UI, not copying the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As an option: if your code really independent on the form, create data module, place TActionList on it, add datamodule unit to the uses clause, assign actions to the Action property of the control (in this case you can just copy control from one form to another) or call that action from event (in this case your have to edit code, but event handler will contains only one line of code)